# How do I write two variable dates in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, date

For an exercise, I'm supposed to write a function with two dates as variable inputs and compare them.
However, whatever way I try to define the function, it gives me an invalid syntax.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
from datetime import date

def birthday(date(year1, month1, day1), date(year2, month2, day2)):
    party = False
    if month1 == month2 and day1 == day2:
        party = True

    return party
```

It is intended that the function be called like this:

```
birthday(date(1969, 10, 5), date(2015, 10, 5))
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to give an example of how you want to call the function?

Comment: https://dodona.ugent.be/en/courses/172/series/1697/exercises/1652696920/

Comment: As a new user to this site, you probably haven't been shown this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: As a new user, I don't have voting up privileges....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't declare the components of the dates in the function arguments because it they are ready-made dates being passed to it, as shown in the examples given, such as

```
birthday(date(1969, 10, 5), date(2015, 10, 5))
```

So you just need to:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

def birthday(date1, date2):
    party = False

    if date1.month == date2.month and date1.day == date2.day:
        party = True

    return party
```

Then you can do

```
bd1 = date(2000, 10, 20)
bd2 = date(2008, 10, 20)
bd3 = date(2000, 10, 1)

print(birthday(bd1, bd2))
print(birthday(bd1, bd3))
```

And get the output

> True
>   False

(You might not need the `import datetime`: I did.)

You could even shorten the function to

```
def birthday(date1, date2):
    return date1.month == date2.month and date1.day == date2.day
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, question is not clear but you can do it in this way:

```
from datetime import date

def birthday(date1,date2):
    party = False
    if date1.month == date2.month and date1.day == date2.day:
        party = True

    return party

date1= date(2019, 4, 13)
date2= date(2019, 4, 13)

print(birthday(date1,date2))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation as to why the OP's function wasn't working could help to get you an upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to compare month and day from 2 dates to check birthday, try blow code:

```
from datetime import date

def bd(d1: date, d2: date) -> bool:
    return d1.month == d2.month and d1.day == d2.day

print(bd(date(1989, 8, 11), date(2019, 8, 11)))
```